# Can't make http://freeastrologyapi.com API request in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node-request

I'm trying to submit an API request based on the tutorial on [FREE ASTROLOGY API](http://freeastrologyapi.com/api-reference/navamsa-chart-info) , but it seems that because the request library is not maintained npm installing it breaks my 100 of my node files all at once. I tried using axios, but I get a lot of errors.

The code works in python, so the API works, but I'm using this for a react web app.

This is the code I tried using:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const url = "https://json.freeastrologyapi.com/navamsa-chart-info";
      const payload = JSON.stringify({
        "year": 2022,
        "month": 8,
        "date": 11,
        "hours": 6,
        "minutes": 0,
        "seconds": 0,
        "latitude": 17.38333,
        "longitude": 78.4666,
        "timezone": 5.5,
        "settings": {
          "observation_point": "topocentric",
          "ayanamsha": "lahiri"
        }
      });
      const headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'x-api-key': 'YOUR_API_KEY_HERE'
      };

      try {
        const response = await axios.post(url, payload, { headers: headers });
        console.log(response.data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

instead of

```
var request = require('request');
var options = {
  'method': 'POST',
  'url': 'https://json.freeastrologyapi.com/navamsa-chart-info',
  'headers': {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'x-api-key': 'YOUR_API_KEY_HERE'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    "year": 2022,
    "month": 8,
    "date": 11,
    "hours": 6,
    "minutes": 0,
    "seconds": 0,
    "latitude": 17.38333,
    "longitude": 78.4666,
    "timezone": 5.5,
    "settings": {
      "observation_point": "topocentric",
      "ayanamsha": "lahiri"
    }
  })

};
request(options, function (error, response) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);
  console.log(response.body);
});
```

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://json.freeastrologyapi.com/navamsa-chart-info' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
Chart.js:119 AxiosErrorcode: "ERR_NETWORK"config: {transitional: {…}, adapter: 'xhr', transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), timeout: 0, …}message: "Network Error"name: "AxiosError"request: XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: null, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …}stack: "AxiosError: Network Error\n    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:51521:14)"[[Prototype]]: Error
fetchData @ Chart.js:119
json.freeastrologyapi.com/navamsa-chart-info:1     Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED

I tried importing npm request , but that broke my project entirely. I tried using axios, but it's not working. I don't suppose I can somehow use the python react script in my react project.

Comment: `request` is a (deprecated) _nodeJS_ library specifically for that environment. You can't use it on the front-end.

Answer (score 0):

The error that you are getting is a [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) error. The API that you are trying to use i.e. `https://json.freeastrologyapi.com/navamsa-chart-info` does not allow it, and thus when you are calling it from a React app (my best guess is, that a react web app, running in a browser) it fails.

You can see the CORS test result [here](https://cors-test.codehappy.dev/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fjson.freeastrologyapi.com%2Fnavamsa-chart-info&origin=https%3A%2F%2Fcors-test.codehappy.dev%2F&method=post)

Workaround?

The best suggestion would be to use any intermediary server (maybe your own server or NextJS?) and then call this API from your server.